# How to call a specific method for each record in a dataframe?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame that contains: a file name, the path to that file, and text to put in that file. I have a method that takes these 3 parameters and creates a file with text, how do I call this method for my dataframe?

DataFrame:

```
|       fileName|     Path|       Text|
+---------------+---------+-----------+
|VelEstDonec.txt|C:\folder|Lorem Ipsum|
| EtUltrices.txt|C:\folder|Lorem Ipsum|
|VelEstDonec.txt|C:\folder|Lorem Ipsum|
| EtUltrices.txt|C:\folder|Lorem Ipsum|
|VelEstDonec.txt|C:\folder|Lorem Ipsum|
| EtUltrices.txt|C:\folder|Lorem Ipsum|
+---------------+---------+-----------+
```

My method:

```
      val fileWithAbsolutePath = new File(path  + fileName)
      val fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName)
      val printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter)
      printWriter.print(text)
    }
```

How do I call this method for my dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A `DataFrame` is a `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset<Row>`. It has a `forEach` method that you can use as follows:

```java
val df = spark.createDataFrame(/*...*/); //Or anyhow you obtain your DataFrame
df.forEach(r -> {
  val fileName = r.getString(0); //fileName is in first column
  val path = r.getString(1);
  val text = r.getString(2);
  //Do something with data, i.e.: callMethod(fileName, path, text);
});
```

2. `path + fileName` won't give you a correct result, as you'll miss a filesystem separator in-between. Rather use `java.nio.file.Paths.get(path).resolve(fileName)`.
   Doc for [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html). Doc for [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)
3. When using resources that need to be closed like `FileWriter` and `PrintWriter`, it is better practice to do so in a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) structure, as those are [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

**Edit: full solution in vanilla Java**

```java
final Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(/*...*/);   //Or anyhow you obtain your DataFrame
df.forEach(r -> {   //Apply lambda expression to each Row
  final String fileName = r.getString(0);  //fileName is in first column
  final String path = r.getString(1);      //path is in second column
  final String text = r.getString(2);      //text is in third column
  final Path fullPath = Paths.get(path, fileName);
  //try-with-resources. Define charset and open mode as create or append
  try (final BufferedWriter w = Files.newBufferedWriter(fullPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
    w.write(text);
    w.newLine(); //If you need each string on a separate line
  } //BufferedWriter closed automatically
});
```

For production code, there would still be a lot of missing error handling...